# How to create field in Django model that refers to another field in the same model

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create field in my Model that refers to another field (in the same model) and modifies it.

My code:

```
class Result(models.Model):
   
      score = models.IntegerField(default=10)
      rank = models.IntegerField(score/2)         // how to point to score from the same model (Result)?
```

Comment: You don't. Normally it is not good to introduce *data duplication* in the database either. Just use a `@property` or annotate if `rank` is always `score/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using django models you're able to create methods hence it would be good practice to implement in your model a method which is kind of a getter (which would be reactive by it's nature so you always could get a right value if score would be changed in future).

```
class Result(models.Model):

  score = models.IntegerField(default=10)
  
  def get_rank(self):
      return self.score / 2
```

but the second way is to override your own speacial save method

```
class Result(models.Model):

  score = models.IntegerField(default=10)
  rank = models.IntegerField()

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs['rank'] = kwargs['score'] / 2
      super(Result, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

so every time when you save your model rank is gonna be counted according to score.